# Latest version of Ubuntu not working properly

Tags: dell

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my lapyop dell Inspiron 3558 and after restart it is not opening it's just black screen with one horizontal line at top left

Answer (score 0):

Before all, try to update your system with this procedure, sometimes it resolves:

Connect your laptop with a wired network (you need an Ethernet cable) to your router and switch to a console pressing CTRL+ALT+F3 or F4 or so ...
Once you have a valid login prompt, insert your login name + return and your password (please note that you won't see any characters you are typing during the password typing ... you have to type it blindly).
Once you successfully log in, type:
sudo apt-get update + return (it will ask your password blindly again) and
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
once finished reboot typing just "reboot" and ... good luck!